# SIM card number swap

Tags: 3g, card-reader

Is it possible to swap two numbers between two sim cards? (I just purchased a new phone and it is using a micro sim) And I have a old number that I want to use but it is on standard sim card. Is it possible to swap the numbers between the cards using a SIM Card reader. What software and hardware should I use?

Note: *I have talked with my provider but I have to cancel my old number's contract. Problem is I like it and do not want to pay the remaining period of the contract to turn it in to PayAsYouGo and then swap...*

Comment: Is this really related to Ubuntu? Like it should be if its on this website.

Comment: this is off topic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the phone number isn't stored on the SIM card itself, and I don't think a transfer is feasible.

However, you can simply cut the old card to turn it into a micro-SIM. Be careful when doing it, though.

Here is a nice little guide with a cutting template: http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-convert-micro-sim-to-nano-sim-for-iphone-5/

If you want to go the other way round, there are adapters specifically designed for this purpose, like this one: http://dx.com/p/micro-sim-card-to-standard-sim-card-adapter-white-41355. I'm sure they are sold in many different places.

Comment: Yes cutting is an option, but how to make the small card bigger.. Cuz that is the reason I wanted to swap them numbers =)

Comment: There are adapters for this, see the edited answer above.